# Midnight commander (mc) copy/move option doesn't work

Tags: centos, ssh, mc

I cannot copy/move file on remote server.
GNU Midnight Commander 4.8.7 installed on remote Centos server

Steps:

- connect to remote server via xterm ssh
- run mc cmd
- set correct directories on both tabs
- select file to copy
- press F5
- correct popup is displayed

[image]

- press ok

Popup disappear but nothing happened, selected file is not copied.